# how to set/organise files [of target] in same folder structure as their duplicates are in source?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, sync

I have two drives with the same files, but the directory structure is totally different.

```
For example, drive A has:
/foo/bar/123.txt
/foo/bar/234.txt
/foo/bar/dir/567.txt

Whereas drive B has:
/some/other/path/123.txt
/bar/doo2/wow/234.txt
/bar/doo/567.txt
```

how to set/organise files [of target] in same folder structure as their duplicates are in source?
plz help !!!